# Physical meaning of Fourier transform of electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, fourier-transform

I have recently been thinking about what is the physical meaning of the Fourier transform of an electric field, and in particular, why does it seem to have different units in frequency and time domains.

We know that we can get the spectral domain representation of an electric field $E(t)$ via Fourier transform

$E(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty E(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$.

An electric field $E(t)$ has units of $\left[\frac{\text{V}}{\text{m}}\right]$, but because unitswise, integration corresponds to multiplication, from the Fourier transformation formula above, it would appear that the electric field in (angular) frequency domain has units of $\left[\frac{\text{Vs}}{\text{m}}\right]$.

Previously, I had always thought of $E(\omega)$ as how much electric field (in V/m) there is present at angular frequency $\omega$. However, as the units of $E(\omega)$ are not V/m, I don't think this is a valid picture. Therefore, I am puzzled as to what physical meaning I should attribute to $E(\omega)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we should distinguish in notation between the time and frequency functions and write, e.g., $$\hat E(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}E(t)e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t}dt \tag{1}.$$

First, assume that you have a harmonic function, say, $E_0(t)=\hat A_0 e^{\mathfrak j \omega_0 t}$ for some complex $\hat A_0$ amplitude at the frequency $\omega_0$. This $E_0(t)$ does *not* have a Fourier transform in the usual sense, since the integral $\hat E(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A_0 e^{\mathfrak j \omega_0 t} e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t}dt$ does not exist. But of course, wish to *interpret* the complex amplitude $\hat A_0$ as being the Fourier transform of $E_0(t)$ in *some* sense, and we can do so if instead of the Fourier integral of eq. (1) we redefine it to be a true amplitude density as
$$\tilde E(\omega) = \lim_{T\to \infty}  \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}E(t)e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}dt \tag{2}.$$
Now the integral
$$\tilde E_0(\omega) = \lim_{T\to \infty}  \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}A_0 e^{\mathfrak j \omega_0 t}e^{-\mathfrak j \omega t}dt \tag{3}$$
*does* exist, and in fact
$$ 
 \tilde E_0(\omega)= \begin{matrix}
A_0  &\text{if } \omega = \omega_0 \\
0 &  \text{if } \omega \ne \omega_0\\
\end{matrix}$$
as required. While this limit procedure is rarely stated explicitly, it is almost always assumed implicitly for the application of Fourier transforms and Fourier series is used mostly for *stationary* processes with functions that do not have convergent integrals. Note too that if the time function, a time process, is a stationary one in a stochastic statistical sense then the mean square integral is used not to define an amplitude density but rather a power spectral density density.

Answer (score 0):

$E(\omega)$ is how much electric field $E(t)$ present at frequency $\omega$ within the span of $\mathrm{d}\omega$. It is thus a density in $\omega$ to have the unit [Vs/m].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).